# why do these queries produce different results?

Tags: mysql

I have run these two queries that look like they do the same thing, but give different results:

```
SELECT COUNT(stage1) AS total 
FROM progress_status 
WHERE stage1 = 3 
AND stage2 != 3 AND stage3 !=3 AND stage4 !=3 AND stage5 !=3;

# total = 90

SELECT COUNT(stage1) AS total 
FROM progress_status 
WHERE stage1 = 3 
AND (stage2,stage3,stage4,stage5) != (3,3,3,3)

# total = 314
```

Comment: You just made an unfounded assertion and asked why it doesn't hold. We need to know more about your assumptions and why you came to them.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal you should have read the answers before commenting. He is quite correct, and it's a good question.

Comment: @Ariel: It was a rhetorical comment, based on _the question itself_ isolated from its answers. The question is lacking sufficient detail to be considered "good" and it is not precisely posed (and though, in this case, you're right in that his intention can be largely guessed, that is not the point). I'm trying to teach the OP to instead write things like "I expected X because Y, but I see Z. Why? And can I see X instead? Is Y invalid somehow?", rather than just "bluerueghlrgh"

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I'm sorry, I don't see what you're not seeing. To me the question is perfectly clear. Maybe it's because I already know about the way these tuple comparisons work.

Comment: @Ariel: It has nothing to do with the subject matter! It's about _question_ quality. There was an illogical assertion ("they look like they do the same thing, but give different results" ?!) and no further reasoning or remarks, making this a poorly-formed question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is doing:

```
AND (stage2 != 3 OR stage3 !=3 OR stage4 !=3 OR stage5 !=3);
```

Comment: Can you back this up with a reference from the documentation? It's just another assertion at present.

Comment: No, I can't and I spent a LONG time searching. As far as I can find it's undocumented (even though I have a memory of reading it somewhere, I just can't find it). I found forum threads asking for documentation with the answer of "It's not". The closest I can find is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html which deals with subqueries, so it's not exactly the same, but basically these types of expression use the `ANY` operator. If you need a search key it's called a tuple comparison - lots of stackoverflow threads, but nothing official that I could find.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165508/where-is-it-authoritatively-documented-what-the-expr-expr-syntax-does :)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Jackpot! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html - you inspired me to keep looking :)

Comment: But that page says it's `AND`, not `OR`.

Answer (score 3):

It's normal:

- Your first query asks all stage columns to be different from 3
- Your second query asks those columns not beeing equal to 3 at the same time,
  so if one is different from 3 record is taken! 
  This query is like you're using `OR` in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

`(stage2,stage3,stage4,stage5) != (3,3,3,3)` is true when `stage2 != 3 OR stage3 !=3 OR stage4 !=3 OR stage5 !=3`